# How much cultural coherence does SE want across sites?

Tags: discussion

The other day, I encountered a question on a relatively new site. Not having rep to edit on my own, I submitted an edit for review. The question was, in my view, off-topic as written, but adding about two sentences of clarification (discussed, no less, on their meta), looked to do the job.

My edit was rejected, and the explanation was: "That's too big of a change to make without permission/discussion with the OP."

In my understanding, the way things work is that the OP licenses the question's content, and now it belongs to the community, and it's up to the community to decide what would constitute an improvement. Completely butchering a question is not polite, but adding a clarification to narrow it into topic? Needing 'OP permission' for that is not the SE I know.

I am not linking here because I am not trying to start a meta-meta-fight. I post this to ask whether it's reasonable for a new community to adopt a policy in which question-writers retain tight editorial control on their questions.

Comment: Another point that is perhaps worth raising is the question of how much site meta documentation to expect to be present before local quirks in SE customs can reasonably be imposed on new users.

Comment: Personally, I think folks are overly gun-shy about edits network-wide. I think adding things like examples, details, additional bullets, etc. should be generally encouraged more.  I DO think it's fine for an OP to roll edits back, but would hope they don't when they're improvements.  All that said, we tend to respect/accept highly different edit tolerances on different sites.

Comment: The issue here for me is that it wasn't the OP -- it was others. If the OP had rolled back, that would have been that.

Comment: Personally, while I tend to rather improve on the wording, formatting and structuring side, I am a bit more generous with rather content-based edits when the question will get closed without those edits anyway. In this case a little more heavily edited question is better than a closed one. But of course I still try to keep the original intent of the question.

Answer (score 8):

I think this really depends on the site, to be honest. The mods on some of the sites I frequent will, themselves, partake to edit a question that is borderline off-topic (or entirely off-topic) but that they think could make an interesting question with some judicious editing.

Particular examples that come to mind:

On [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), subjects of [health and nutrition](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off topic because they can be problematic, plus there's a [SE site](https://health.stackexchange.com/) to discuss them now, anyway.

But, sometimes, the health points a question makes can be removed without changing what the question is asking, as here:

[Is there a substitute for aluminum foil?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18346/is-there-a-substitute-for-aluminum-foil)

The original version of the question discussed a common myth about aluminum being unsafe, which would have made the question off-topic but the main point of the question "What can be used as  a substitute for aluminum foil?", is perfectly fine... for all we know you simply can't find any or you ran out.

Similarly, on Movies & TV, we occasionally get some questions that are, essentially, "[This movie is crappy, why is it so critically acclaimed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37307/why-is-a-clockwork-orange-considered-great)". These questions can be borderline subjective with a touch of rant-y-ness, so the mods will attempt to fix the question to ask for some specific points to help readers appreciate the film's contributions to film history.

As others have noted, it's up to each community to decide how much editing is acceptable. That being said, I believe editing of questions to have more flexibility than editing answers. A question may have many answers but only one question. The question should benefit the entire community (as you say), not only the asker, so if a question needs some judicious editing to be more useful to the community, I think that's fine, **particularly** if the question is borderline off-topic to begin with.

I would strongly suggest you ask this question on the site's meta so that you can get some direct conversation going on that site. Perhaps your conversation there will help to set site policy, which is such an important part of the Beta process (you say it's a new site, so I'm assuming it's still in Beta).

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote,

> it's up to the community to decide what would constitute an improvement.

So, if a Stack Exchange community decides that narrowing the scope of a question is too much of an edit to make... then it is too much of an edit to make by *that community's standards*.

Every community sets their own standards for asking, answering, commenting, editing, etc. The differences can be very noticeable.

I'll link to one example since I believe the dust has firmly settled upon it:  [Why were my edits rejected?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2599) (This is from [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), a very successful and very different community from most others.)

> Since every site is community-driven, we try to adapt things to our reality and not the other way around. Our methods would probably not work in other sites, say Math.SX or Spanish.SX. Sometimes, when I hear the words "SE policy" said in the wild, the walking hammers from The Wall come to my mind. Don't get this wrong, but I feel it sounds like an imposition: share it fairly but don't take a slice of my pie. I prefer to look at the SE policy as an inspiration for communities to work with a predefined set of suggestions and, as time goes by, work on their own methods, adapted to their own reality.